# Laravel doesn't save, but returns true

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using latest Laravel with this code in the Controller:

```
function changeProperty(Request $request){

    if(Car::find('id', 34)->save(array('expired' => true))){
        return [
            'success' => true,
            'check' => Car::find(34)
        ];
    }

    return [
        'success' => false
    ];
}
```

and I am getting `success => true`, but when I check in PHPMyAdmin, the value is not saved.
In the `Property::find(34)` I see that Car is selected, but with not updated value `expired`, too, which by default is 0.

This is part of the `Car` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'expired'
];
```

This is the migration for the cars table:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->boolean('expired')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be:

```
Car::find('id', 34)->update($params)
```

`save()` does not accept attributes as a parameter.